# UIScrollView bounces on object press

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UIScrollView with a bunch of buttons and switches present in it. When pressing any of these items the scroll view bounces to the top of the screen. While debugging this issue I increased the content size of the scroll view to be much larger than the space that I require and the issue does not happen. I should also mention that in in the hierarchy of objects within this view controller I do not have a UIView is it possible this could be causing my problem. I have tried adding a one in but it seems to break a lot of the UIScrollView features. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening or what hierarchy structure should be employed when using a UIScrollView.

Thanks.

Comment: Everything visual is a UIView. Buttons, Images, etc. adding a blank one to act as s container for everything else shouldn't affect the scroll view at all